# Countdowntimer works in short intervals, but not others

Tags: android

I am facing an interesting situation, maybe someone could explain to me why.

I am doing timer that runs at interval of 100 msec.  At every tick, a textview is updated to show the time. Also there  is a an edit text with a text watched in which the string is compared 2 times to different strings After each Text changed

When I use Timer class, then the thread seems to be busy because I can't type any  text into the edit text . When I use handler same problem happens. But if I use countdowntimer class then it works.

Interestingly, if I increase the interval to 1 sec then all of the above works.

1-is 100 msec too short? I didint think the above computations I making would  take that long. 
2-  why countdowntimer worked and other  failed?

Thank you